# Calculate all possible positions of 1 in a bit array

Tags: c#

I have a method that receives a number `n` as parameter and calculate all possible  combinition containing exactly `n 1` in a bit(0,1) array, the result returned is the positions of the number 1

for example suppose that our bit array has `3` elements and

```
 for n = 1
   the function gives : [0] - [1] - [2] (three possible positions)
 for n=2
   the result will be [0,1] -  [0,2] - [1,2] (three possible positions)
```

and for n=3
       the result will be [0,1,2] (one possible position)

the function work correctly for an array with 3 elements, but gives wrong results for 4 elements

```
  n = 2 result : [0,1] - [0,2] - [0,3] -[1,2] - [1,3] - [1,2,3]
```

Can any one explain why it gives unexpected results for arraysize >= 4

Thanks in advance

```
    const int arraySize = 4;

    static private void Positions(int n, int start, ArrayList prepend, ArrayList results)
    {
        ArrayList tmp = new ArrayList(prepend);
        int end = arraySize - n;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            if (end < arraySize - 1)
            {
                prepend.Add(i);
                Positions(n - 1, i + 1, prepend, results);                    
                prepend = tmp;
            }
            else
                results.Add(new ArrayList(prepend) { i });
        }
    }
```

this is how i use the method

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList();            
        Positions(2, 0, new ArrayList(), results);

        foreach (ArrayList array in results)
        {
            foreach (var elem in array)
                Console.Write(elem);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: For your 3 elements, n=2, shouldn't it be `[0,1] - [0,2] - [1,2]`?

Comment: @mellamokb you are right i edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in this line:

```
prepend = tmp;
```

You are intending I think to restore the state of the prepend array to the original at the beginning of the method.  However, you are setting a direct reference, so with every loop iteration you are modifying the original prepend array.  If you copy the array here as well every time, it seems to work correctly:

```
prepend = new ArrayList(tmp);
```

All this copying of arrays, however, is not very efficient.  You can try removing the entry you just added as well as another alternative:

```
prepend.Add(i);
Positions(n - 1, i + 1, prepend);
prepend.Remove(i);
```

Then technically you don't even need the `tmp` copy any more.

**Edit**: Also, for your `if` statement, I think you want something like

```
if (n > 1)
```

Comment: prepend.Remove(i) throws an exception

Comment: It worked for me when I tested in LINQPad. What's the exception?

Comment: Ah. I forgot I did make another change.  I changed the if statement to `if (n > 1)` which is what I think you intended.

Comment: Even with `if(n > 1)` it throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Can you provide a fully-working, stand-alone code snippet that I can run in LINQPad?  I had to finagle with your parameters to get it to work because of the static properties.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Here's your exact code copy-pasted with the one change I suggested, works just fine: http://ideone.com/1jqVs (it looks like your original `if` statement is also just fine)

Comment: Very strange, the code you posted is the same as mine but, mine fails and yours works. tell me what is LINQPad?

Comment: [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a free tool for running .NET code without starting up Visual Studio and making an entire project.  You can just run simple snippets of code quick and easy.  Can you determine what line of code is generating that error message?

Comment: Ok it works fine by mistake i used RemoveAt instead of Remove, thanks again